# If you are using AWS to autoscale spot instances of your application, how do you handle logging?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

Looking into adding autoscaling of a portion of our application using AWS simple message queuing which would launch EC2 on-demand or spot instances based on queue backlog.

One question I had, is how do you deal with collecting logs from autoscaled instances? New instances are spun up based on an image, but then they are shut down when complete. Currently, if there is an issue with one of our services, which causes it to crash, we have a system to automatically restart the service, but the logs and core dump files are there to review. If we switch to an autoscaling system, where new instance are spun up, how do you get logs and core dump files when there is a failure? Particularly if the instance is spun down.

Answer (score 2):

Good practice is to ship these logs and aggregate them somewhere else, and there are many services such as DataDog and Rapid7 which will do this for you at a cost.

AWS however provides CloudWatch logs, which gives you a central place to store and view logs. It also allows you then to give users access to logs on the AWS console without them having to ssh onto a server.

Shipping your logs to CloudWatch logs requires the installation of the CloudWatch agent on your server and specifying in the config which logs to ship.

You could install the CloudWatch agent once and create an AMI of that server to use in your autoscaling group, or install and configure the CloudWatch agent in userdata for every time a server is spun up.

All the information you need to get started can be found here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html

Comment: How would this work for core dumps? Can CloudWatch grab them?